# Flutter Web sliver: customscrollview

Tags: flutter, layout

I'm making a flutter web.
I want to resize a horizontal image in a CustomScrollView.

Ex: On a product detail page, I want to place the top image size 600x400 width in the center of the layout.

Regardless of the image size, it is a problem that it expands to 900x or more horizontally.

layout: [image]

code:

```
class ServiceProductDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String productId;
  final ServiceProductModel product;
  ServiceProductDetailPage({required this.product, required this.productId});    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [      
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 50,
            title: Text('Title'),
            stretch: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),      
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: _Body(context, _product)),        
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _Body(BuildContext context, ServiceProductModel product) {
  return Card(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(900,400)
      ),
      child: LoadingImage(url: product.image),
    ),
  );
}

class LoadingImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String url;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.network(
      url,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      errorBuilder: (BuildContext c, Object err, StackTrace? stack) {
        return const Center(child: Text('error'));},
      frameBuilder: (BuildContext c, Widget image, int? frame, bool sync){
        if (!sync && frame == null) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return image;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. Could you better explain what you are trying to achieve and what you are currently getting ?

Comment: I want to create a layout with a center width of 900x. When I run this code, the image width is expanded to the maximum.

Comment: So you want your image to be just 600*400 and not expand to 900. Is this what you are saying ?

Comment: I want to expand to 900x400 size, but the image will take up the entire browser. Expanding beyond 900 is a problem. I only want it to expand to the size of the layout width.

Comment: Do you want your `_Body` widget to be only 900 and then the image inside to needs to expand to 900 width, correct ?

Comment: Yes, the _Body widget is fixed at 900, and the problem is that it expands to 900 or more regardless of the current IMAGE size.

Comment: Got it. let me try and fix it.

Comment: Post your full code. Your `StickNavBarHeader` and `LoadingImage` widgets are required to debug this.

Comment: Added LoadingImage source. update..

Comment: Added an answer. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an `UnconstrainedBox`. As per the documentation, the `UnconstrainedBox` makes itself take the full width of it's parent, but it allows it's `child` to be of any width the `child` decides.

So, you can use it like this.

```
Widget _Body(BuildContext context, ServiceProductModel product) {
  return Card(
    child: UnconstrainedBox(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        width: 900,
        height: 400,
        child: LoadingImage(url: product.image),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Next, you given some properties to you `Image.network` that is making it expand.

So remove the following

```
fit: BoxFit.cover,
width: double.infinity,
height: double.infinity,
```

And just add this

```
fit: BoxFit.contain,
```

I have given your `900` width `Container` a `color` to see that it stays at `900` despite the window being larger than `900`.

[image: Output]

Comment: UncontrainedBox() is a good suggestion, but placing other widgets above and below it throws an error.
I want to place all widgets including images in the center of the layout.
It should also be a responsive web. I will test a little more.

Comment: That should still be possible using `SliverLists` or other `Sliver` variants of normal widgets. What are you trying to place and what error is coming ?

Comment: I want to create a UI similar to the Figma community details page(https://www.figma.com/community/file/973059007705843962). I also tested the placement of several widgets using SliverLists. The problem didn't fix the widget being off-center. I think you will find out if you test a little more